# Midnight Commander's viewer can't search in some files

Tags: mc

I'm often using "F3 View" in Midnight Commander, and I just found out that using search feature "F7 Search" doesn't always work correctly. What I found out is that when file has extension "txt" or "log", then no problems whatsoever, but if a file has extension "1", "2", etc up to "9" (from logrotate) then search is broken for them. By "broken" I mean that it only searches in small part of the file, not whole file like it should. I also noticed that when search is working ok mc shows in upper right corner "3914/2672K 0%", but when search is not working as it should then it shows only "3502/8192+". And no, I'm not searching in compressed files, this happens with pure text files. If I change extension from "1" to "txt" then search works without problems.
So is this a configuration problem, or a bug in mc?

Comment: https://midnight-commander.org/wiki/NewTicket